# Need help laying out a text and a separator widget in a row so that the separator has a min width and expands when the text does not fill out the row

Tags: flutter

I have a row with a text and a separator widget. The separator widget should have a min width, and expand if the text widget does not fill out the remaining width of the row. The text widget should overflow and show and ellipsis if it does not fit in the remaining width of the row (total width - min separator width).

How can I achieve this behavior on Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit on 2021/06/26

OK I figure something out, it's a little more complex but it worked as requirement, you can set minimum width on separator.

```
  Widget _row(String text, int number) => Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              children: [
                Container(height: 2, color: Colors.black),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(width: 60, height: 2, color: Colors.black),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Text(number.toString()),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

---

Not sure if it is possible to put min width on separator as you wanted, but it'll be a lot easier if you put **max width on Text**:

```
Widget _row(String text, int number) => Row(
      children: [
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
          child: Text(
            text,
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(height: 2, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        Text(number.toString()),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Yeah, that definitely works. I've considered using MediaQuery to limit the text's width to a certain percentage of the screen width, but I'd rather not use a fixed width for the text. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: Hey, I have just revisited this and saw your edit. That actually worked, thanks a lot.